# D3.js combining bar and line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I want to create a multiple series chart, by combining a bar with a line chart. When I use the `rangeBands()` for setting the output range, the line begins to be drawn at the beginning of the first bar, and ends at the beginning of the last bar from the chart. What should I change so the line begins over the fist tick and ends over the last tick?

```js
var data = [{ date: '1-May-12', close: 58.13, open: 7.41 }, { date: '2-May-12', close: 53.98, open: 45.55 }, { date: '3-May-12', close: 67.00, open: 11.78}];

var margin = { top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
 width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, width], .09); // <-- to change the width of the columns, change the .09 at the end to whatever
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
 .orient("bottom")
 .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y"));

var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
 .orient("left");

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
 .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
 .y(function (d) { return y(d.open); });

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform",
  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
data.forEach(function (d) {
 d.date = parseDate(d.date);
 d.close = +d.close;
 d.open = +d.open;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.close; })]);

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .call(yAxisLeft);

// Draw the bars
svg.selectAll("bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .style("fill", "#99ffcc")
  .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.date); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.close); })
  .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.close); });

// Add the valueline path
svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", valueline(data));
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px Arial;
}
path {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adjust the line functions x accessor by half the rangeband:

```
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.date) + x.rangeBand()/2; })
    .y(function (d) { return y(d.open); });
```

---

Full Code:

```js
var data = [{ date: '1-May-12', close: 58.13, open: 7.41 }, { date: '2-May-12', close: 53.98, open: 45.55 }, { date: '3-May-12', close: 67.00, open: 11.78}];

var margin = { top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
 width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, width], .09); // <-- to change the width of the columns, change the .09 at the end to whatever
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
 .orient("bottom")
 .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y"));

var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
 .orient("left");

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
 .x(function (d) { return x(d.date) + x.rangeBand()/2; })
 .y(function (d) { return y(d.open); });

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform",
  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
data.forEach(function (d) {
 d.date = parseDate(d.date);
 d.close = +d.close;
 d.open = +d.open;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.close; })]);

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .call(yAxisLeft);

// Draw the bars
svg.selectAll("bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .style("fill", "#99ffcc")
  .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.date); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.close); })
  .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.close); });

// Add the valueline path
svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", valueline(data));
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px Arial;
}
path {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```