# D3.js Combining Candlestick Chart with Line Graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg, charts

I am trying to plot a moving average on top of a candlestick chart but the "path" is not appearing completely on the svg canvas that I created. 
I have tried looking at several post on how to put a line on top of a bar graph (because I figured it would be similar) but it has not worked.

A couple of the examples and post I have looked at are below:

https://bl.ocks.org/nanu146/f48ffc5ec10270f55c9e1fb3da8b38f0
[d3.js How to add lines to a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230979/d3-js-how-to-add-lines-to-a-bar-chart)
[D3.js combining bar and line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435384/d3-js-combining-bar-and-line-chart)

I have all the data in a array.

I am using the same x "scale" for both the candle stick graph and the moving average (line). I have tried using the same y "scale" for both the line and the candlestick but it did not work. Therefore i tried creating 2 scales for y, one for the moving average and one for the candlestick chart. That is what Im doing in my code below.

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var twoHundredDayCandleStickChart = [];

//pulling from 2 properties so must do this way
@for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
    {
        @:twoHundredDayCandleStickChart.push({date: '@Model.DailyTimeSeriesData.Data.ElementAt(i).Key', high: '@Model.DailyTimeSeriesData.Data.ElementAt(i).Value.high', low: '@Model.DailyTimeSeriesData.Data.ElementAt(i).Value.low', open: '@Model.DailyTimeSeriesData.Data.ElementAt(i).Value.open', close: '@Model.DailyTimeSeriesData.Data.ElementAt(i).Value.close', sma: '@Model.TwoHundredDaySma.Data.ElementAt(i).Value.Sma'})
    }

console.log(twoHundredDayCandleStickChart);

    var width = 900;
    var height = 500;
    var margin = 50;

    function min(a, b) { return a < b ? a : b; }

    function max(a, b) { return a > b ? a : b; }

    //y for the candlestick
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - margin, margin]);

    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([margin, width - margin]);

    //y for the line
    var y1 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - margin, margin]);

    //line for the sma
    var line1 = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d["date"]); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d["sma"]); });

    function buildChart(data) {

        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = new Date(d.date);
            d.high = +d.high;
            d.low = +d.low;
            d.open = +d.open;
            d.close = +d.close;
            d.sma = +d.sma;
        });

    var chart = d3.select("#twoHundredDaySmaWithCandleStickChart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("class", "chart")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    //map is going to create an array with all the lows and then d3.min will take the min out of all of them
    y.domain([d3.min(data.map(function (x) { return x["low"]; })), d3.max(data.map(function (x) { return x["high"]; }))])

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d["date"]; }))

    y1.domain(d3.extent(68, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d["sma"]; })))


    //grid for the chart; x and y axis
    chart.selectAll("line.x")
        .data(x.ticks(10))
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "x")
        //.text(String)
        .attr("x1", x)
        .attr("x2", x)
        .attr("y1", margin)
        .attr("y2", height - margin)
        .attr("stroke", "#ccc");
    chart.selectAll("line.y")
        .data(y.ticks(10))
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "y")
        .attr("x1", margin)
        .attr("x2", width - margin)
        .attr("y1", y)
        .attr("y2", y)
        .attr("stroke", "#ccc");


    //x axis
    chart.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 450 + ")") //need to change this 450 to a variable- it is how far down the axis will go
        .attr("class", "xrule")   // give it a class so it can be used to select only xaxis labels  or change color
        //the x axis                        
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "rotate(-65)"
        });

    //the y axis
    chart.selectAll("text.yrule")
        .data(y.ticks(10))
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "yrule")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("dy", 0)
        .attr("dx", 20)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(String);

    //add rectangles- if open higher then close then red
    chart.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d["date"]); })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return y(max(d["open"], d["close"])); })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return y(min(d["open"], d["close"])) - y(max(d["open"], d["close"])); })
        .attr("width", function (d) { return 0.5 * (width - 2 * margin) / data.length; })
        .attr("fill", function (d) { return d["open"] > d["close"] ? "red" : "green"; });

    //add a stem to the rectangle
    chart.selectAll("line.stem")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "stem")
        .attr("x1", function (d) { return x(d["date"]) + 0.25 * (width - 2 * margin) / data.length; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return x(d["date"]) + 0.25 * (width - 2 * margin) / data.length; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return y(d["high"]); })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return y(d["low"]); })
        .attr("stroke", function (d) { return d.open > d.close ? "red" : "green"; });

    chart.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("d", line1)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2);


}

buildChart(twoHundredDayCandleStickChart);
</script>
```

The above code is giving me the image below:

[image: Candlestick chart with SMA]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in the chart above was my scales! I was taking the domain for the candle stick data but the line data was a lot lower of a min. Therefore the whole graph was not showing up on the scale because the min of the domain had to be adjusted. MANY hours wasted but hopefully this can save someone else time!

Answer (score 0):

d3.select("#twoHundredDaySmaWithCandleStickChart")

Try to change the above code like below

d3.select("svg") or give the div Id

Comment: twoHundredDaySmaWithCandleStickChart is the Id name for a div in my html